# Apps crashing after updating Lenovo A2010 to Android 5.1 Lollipop

Tags: updates, 5.1-lollipop, ota-update, crashes, lenovo

I updated my Lenovo A2010-a to the latest version (Android 5.1): I just clicked on a message that says "You have a new update. Update has downloaded and can be installed" then it opened a new window. On that window, I click on the button "install", then the phone rebooted and was updating (showing a green Android icon). The battery was in normal condition (not low). After that, the phone booted normally.

After updating, I have an error on all applications installed on my phone. Error for all applications in one separate window, one after one. With text like this (translated from Russian to English)

> Error in application "Google Keyboard"

What I can do to resolve that problem?

Answer (score 1):

In the end, I came to the Lenovo site and chose to chat with the tech support.

They say:

> You need to reset the phone to factory config.

That's all.

Comment: That's not restricted to Lenovo. Those people in 1st level support are no "techies". They've got a list with known issues like "case X: do a". As it is with `case` statements, they have a "fallback" if none of the "named" conditions matches. With smartphone 1st level, that's always "default: do factory-reset; if that doesn't solve it, have the device sent in". So to decide whether your post is an answer: did a factory-reset solve the issue? Side-note: I've recommended "wipe cache and Dalvik". Can't be done with stock recovery and no root without doing a factory-reset.

Comment: Thank you, Izzy! But I already reset my phone to factory config. :) Now it working fine.

Comment: I expected as much. Basically this confirms what I suggested with my comment on your question. I will convert that comment to an answer for others to benefit from.

Answer (score 0):

#### Some background

While [Lenovo suggested](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/152271/16575) doing a [factory-reset](/questions/tagged/factory-reset) (which always is the last-resort you get by support hotlines before they have you sent-in your device), this would have been easier to resolve (without data loss) – provided either your device is rooted, or you have a custom recovery available:

Whenever you switch to a different ROM, or upgrade/downgrade to a different Android version, it is recommended to wipe your cache and Dalvik/ART cache. Background is that different ROMs/Android-versions use different versions of the Dalvik/ART engine which might have (subtle or not-so-subtle) difference in structures – so when the "new version" accesses structures of the "previous version" which it doesn't understand, it leads to problems as described in the question.

For OTA updates provided "the official way", the responsibility to take care for that lies in the vicinity of the provider: Their update script(s) running on a level having access to both, and thus should take care to wipe cache as well as Dalvik/ART cache when needed (so blame them if they didn't).

If you flash a custom ROM, this task lies in *your* vicinity – as the "ROM cook" cannot know in advance if you're flashing it over a different ROM/version. Installation instructions for those custom ROMs usually include that step.

#### TL;DR

If you happen to be in the situation as described in the question, but don't want to root your device or install a custom recovery, you can either perform a factory-reset (WARNING: all your data and the apps you've installed are lost then, so take care having a good [backup](/questions/tagged/backup) at hand) – or you can ***boot** (not install) a custom recovery once to wipe cache and Dalvik/ART. One recovery usually supporting that is [twrp](/questions/tagged/twrp):

There's a [guide to *install* TWRP on the Lenovo A2010](https://dottech.org/193917/how-to-install-twrp-recovery-on-lenovo-a2010/) which includes a [link to download TWRP for this device](https://yadi.sk/d/0WaK6e4Mkx5cx) (**Note:** I cannot vouch for the safety of those sites or integrity of the download – so better check yourself for a reliable source, or verify this one).

Once you have the TWRP image file, you also need the [fastboot](/questions/tagged/fastboot) tool on your computer. Boot your device into [bootloader](/questions/tagged/bootloader) mode, then run `fastboot boot twrp.img` (replace `twrp.img` with the name of the `.img` file you've got). Now your device will boot up into TWRP. Select to wipe cache and wipe Dalvik/ART, let it perform the action, then have it reboot normally. TWRP will be gone from your device, and everything should be "back to normal" – while no data have been lost.

Answer (score 0):

I've just recovered from this issue by removing all updates of Google Play Services. The procedure is quite tricky, since "Application stopped working ..." messages keep popping up. But after you confirm about the first 20 popups, they pop up more slowly and it is somewhat possible to navigate through menus.

Open Settings from the device pull-down menu, select Applications -> All -> Google Play Services -> Remove all updates (it may ask for deactivating device manager, confirm deactivation). Wait for the uninstallation to proceed, then long power button press -> Reboot. Upon next boot you should see "Optimizing application x/n", it takes a while, but the phone should be usable again.

Then you should upgrade Google Play Services and reboot again to have a fresh version.