# Error: Unfortunately [every app] has stopped working

Tags: updates

I recently updated my Lenovo A2010-a via OTA  and after the update, it shows "Unfortunately, [every third party app] has stopped working" 
Only system apps work now. 
How to fix it?

Comment: Did you try reinstalling them?

Comment: It sounds Like the davlik was not wiped, which is **not** your fault. I don't often support one-line answers but the one below is spot on. @esQmo is also right, though It may be a bit of a nightmare :)

Comment: Check this question:
http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/152190/trouble-with-update-android-lenovo-a2010-a/169622#169622

Answer (score 1):

Try factory resetting your phone, but backup important data first.